# Import-Module won't work when launched from .net

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm trying to run a powershell script within my C# web application.

When i run the following in powershell, it works fine.

```
Import-Module 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\\80\\Service\\NavAdminTool.ps1'

Get-NAVTenant -ServerInstance DynamicsHost
```

But when i'm running it using my web application, it tells me

> The term 'Get-NAVTenant -ServerInstance DynamicsHost' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Here is my c# code:

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\\80\\Service\\NavAdminTool.ps1" });
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
    runspace.Open();
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-NAVTenant -ServerInstance DynamicsHost");

    foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction??

UPDATE:

Using runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("Error") i could see the following error:

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
>
> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>
> Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\80\Service' because it does not exist.
>
> A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.
>
> A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.
>
> A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935680/517852) may help you troubleshoot. You can get the module import errors from `runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("Error")`.

Comment: You have to add the cmdlet and its args separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that the developer web server could't handle the request. Switching to IIS as developer server solved the problem. Now both of watto's examples works.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that your entire command string is interpreted as the name of a (non-existent) cmdlet. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the `AddCommand()` method expects the name of a cmdlet, while parameters should be added via `AddParameter()`.

Try changing this:

```
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-NAVTenant -ServerInstance DynamicsHost");
```

into this:

```
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-NAVTenant");
ps.Commands.AddParameter("-ServerInstance", "DynamicsHost");
```

or this:

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-NAVTenant");
ps.AddParameter("-ServerInstance", "DynamicsHost");
```

Answer (score 1):

I can verify the following code works, posted from above: the following code will return the DatabaseServer name of the specified Dynamics NAV service tier

```
        InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\\80\\Service\\NavAdminTool.ps1" });
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
        runspace.Open();
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Runspace = runspace;
        ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-NAVTenant");
        ps.Commands.AddParameter("-ServerInstance", "objectupgrade");                        

        foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["DatabaseServer"].Value);
        }
        Console.Read();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

A better and a much quicker method is to use the Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Management snap-in directly. Significant performance improvement can be seen by using this method. Please see following code found here: [Why does PowerShell class not load a snapin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338554/why-does-powershell-class-not-load-a-snapin)

```
        var config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException warning;
        config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Management", out warning);

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddCommand("Get-NAVTenant");
                ps.AddParameter("ServerInstance", "ObjectUpgrade");
                Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["DatabaseServer"].Value);                            
                }
                Console.Read();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first code you posted still returns: 
{"The term 'Get-NAVTenant' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."}

Comment: The second cannot find Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Management.. I gues that I need to install the management package?

Comment: Sorry, yes I assumed that you had already Dynamics NAV already installed.

Comment: Interesting though ... none of the above mentioned code works in a .Net application, specifically in an API. If you have any ideas why not i'd love to hear them.

Comment: Maybe i should have read your comment at the beginning. I've just described your issue as well.  .

Comment: The reason why it did not work was, that the developper webserver that comes with visual studio can't use the modules.. When I ran the exact same code on the IIS 8.0 it worked fine..